# How to query and persist static objects in MySQL Database with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am working on a Restful service built with Java Spring and I have some issues modeling the data. I want to store shelfs with books. The books belong to a given category. I have a POST request to store shelfs to a mysql database (via service and CrudRepository). However I am not able to store more than one book of the same category. Here are my (simplified) entities.

A Shelf with an id and a collection of books.

```
@Entity
public class Shelf{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "shelf")
    private List<Book> books= new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

The class Book is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Book{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Shelf shelf;
```

Each book belongs to a category(e.g. thriller, fiction, etc.). Here is the category entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
```

And finally my Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ShelfController {

    @Autowired
    private ShelfService shelfService;

    @PostMapping("/shelfs")
    public Shelf addShelf(@RequestBody Shelf shelf) {

        return shelfService.addShelf(shelf);
    }
```

Now here is my problem: The categories will be given and there will be no option to change these, I would therefore like to have them stored in the database or hard code them as static objects. In the Post request for new shelfs I would like to provide only the category id and make the controller find the corresponding object itself.
What I did so far was to treat the categories as a usual Entity, so whenever I added a new shelf with books having a category_id, the category was created with the given id and an empty name. But as soon as I used the same category id again, the application threw a `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` exception. I don't want the controller to create new category objects, but instead want it to fetch the corresponding objects from a service or a static Collection.

So my question is: How can I achieve this?

Hints for solutions/tricks to improve the design are most welcome, I am new to the topic.

Comment: If you have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, save will be cascaded, you might want to remove it for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create Data Transfer Objects (DTO). Example:

```
class ShelfDTO {
    private Long id;
    private List<Long> bookIds;
}
```

Then use this class to receive the `POST` requests:

```
@RestController
public class ShelfController {

    @Autowired private ShelfService shelfService;

    @PostMapping("/shelfs")
    public Shelf addShelf(@RequestBody ShelfDTO shelfDto) {
        return shelfService.addShelf(shelfDto);
    }
}
```

Then modify your `ShelfService` to convert the DTO to an Entity:

```
@Service
public class ShelfService {

    @Autowired private ShelfRepository shelfRepository;
    @Autowired private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Shelf addShelf(ShelfDTO shelfDto) {
        List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAllById(shelfDto.getBookIds());
        return shelfService.addShelf(new Shelf(books));
    }
}
```

Final comment: I noticed that you have a bidirectional relationship. You are responsible for keeping it in a consistent state.

The easiest way is to create the methods `addTo(shelf, book)` and `removeFrom(shelf, book)` that encapsulate the logic of both adding the book to the list in the shelf and setting the shelf in the book.